# Are reward box contents set when you obtain them or when you open them?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I've begun receiving reward boxes in my inventory, and am wondering if their contents are determined when I obtain them, or when I actually open them. Their description says "*This box must be opened to reveal its contents. A box holding an assortment of items.*"

So, for example, would the contents of a box obtained at level 5 be of higher value if I waited to open it until I'm at level 10?

Comment: I don't know for sure but after several playthroughs I would say the contents are set when you get it. In any case the really good stuff most often comes from the strongest machines.